# Blender to unity track animations

Tags: animation, objects, unity

I have been banging my on this for a whole week trying to figure it out. But everything I try is giving me the same results.

I created an animation on a windshield and landing hears with track constraints on different objects. The results look really good, and I did not think I would have this much trouble to export to unity.

Here is what the results look like:
[image]
[image]

I was actually really proud of the results and then decided to see what they looked like in unity.

Here are the results... :(

[image]
[image]

The last two gifs are kind of fast because they had to be small enough to be uploaded, so the frames are not too many.

But you are still able to see the difference between the first pictures and last.

I know some one might have encountered this before. I need your help please. I don't know what else to try.
Is this kind of animation not translatable to unity? do I need to be using another program instead.?

I don't really know what info would be helpful to give you guys, but I don't think I'm doing anything too complicated here.

I know you guys rock and you will be able to help. Please again, ask if you need more info and I will give as much as I can.

Comment: As far as I know to export animations to any application they have to be armature based, constraints are non transferable, from what I gather. Even then only FBX and Collada are able to export animations, and issues are always expected for this king of complexa data.

Comment: Duarte is right. Don't even bother to try to animate it without bones. It's always gonna give poor results, cause you got plenty of elements, that have different origin points, different rotations and so on. With an armature it'll be much cleaner and easier job. Since you already committed so much work to it try my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try to bake action. With selected all objects, that you need to be animated (so without empties) go to Tool Shelf>Animation>Bake Action, choose Only selected, Visual Keying, Clear Constraints, Clear Parents and Overwrite Current Action. For Bake Data select Object and for End Frame and Start Frame appropriate frames on which your animation starts and ends.Animation, that will be effect of that should be easy exportable to Unity.

[image]

Comment: baking the animation to the landing gear worked and it looks good now. but when the cockpit opens, it is still the same issue, objects are still rotated incorrectly. I guess i will try to do it with bones. Im just not sure how i will do that yet.

Comment: I tried removing the keyframes and empties and also the track constraints, and the objects still have the wrong rotation. I think this is something else, not due to animation...